# Thesis Signature Page

Tags: spacing, line, signatures

I must create a signature page. I have searched through this board for similar examples but I don't see any that match this type of style. Unfortunately, I'm quite new to creating my own page styles in LaTeX so I'm not sure what packages or commands to start with.

Here is an image of what it needs to look like:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Have you searched for a LaTeX class or template for your university already? Chances are someone who preferred to hack around with LaTeX instead of finish their thesis has already done this work.

Comment: I checked overleaf because they have a crazy amount of templates, but my university doesn't have anything on there or anything that comes close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may have very exact specifications, and I can't tell what they would be from just an image, but something like this should get you started:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent We approve the thesis of Darth Maul

\bigskip

\hfill \parbox{1.5in}{Date of Signature}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\noindent\rule{4in}{0.7pt} \hfill \rule{1.5in}{0.7pt}

\noindent Darth Malak\\
Professor, Department of Chemistry and Biochemistry\\
Thesis Advisor

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\noindent\rule{4in}{0.7pt} \hfill \rule{1.5in}{0.7pt}

\noindent Darth Sion\\
Professor, Department of Chemistry and Biochemistry\\
University of Sichuan Gourmet Kitchen\\
Thesis Committee

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

(etc.)

\end{document}
```

[image: signature page]

Tweak as needed.

Comment: Wow, that was a very fast build. That looks good to me. Hopefully they don't find something wrong with it. For all I know, they measure these things with rulers though considering some of the requests they make